# Search bar that hides all elements until search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my search bar hide all of the elements until the user actually searches for them.`[Heres a JSfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/68wbnu8e/1/)

```
    <div id="search">
              <form>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="myInput" onkeyup="mFunction()" 
   placeholder="Search ?..">
 </form>
 <nav>
 <table id="myTable">
 <tr class="header">
<th style="width:500px;">Question</th>
</tr>
<tr>  
 <td onclick="window.location.href='#web'">What is the company email?</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td onclick="window.location.href='#web'">Is the website currently under 
development?</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td onclick="window.location.href='#game'">Why are the games not working 
online?</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td onclick="window.location.href='#game'">What is the next game or games 
 that you are working on?</td>

</tr>

<tr>
 <td onclick="window.location.href='#game'">Are you working on Modern Jewels 
 anymore?</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td onclick="window.location.href='#game'">What are the controls for Modern 
 Jewels?</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </nav>`
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
    function mFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search 
  query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Do you know how, it is for a FAQ page and I want the users to be able to search for the questions without a load of questions all in the search.

Thanks any help appreciated :D

Comment: Build a fiddle or code snippet that we can run / see function, please.  SO supports rich code snippets that will allow you to run HTML / JS easily, right in this question.  Otherwise, you shift all of the work on to us to try and recreate the situation, when we're here to help *troubleshoot* for you!

Comment: You've shown us a bunch of code, and somewhat described your goal, but you haven't explained what isn't working or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could done this, by checking on `keyup` in your search. if the value is empty, then you can hide all of your table, else, you can show `td` in `table` which `contains` your search

```
$('table').hide();
$('#myInput').on("keyup", function(){
    var searchVal = $('#myInput').val();
    if(searchVal == ""){
        $('table').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('table').show();
        $('table tr td').show();
        $('table tr td:not(:contains("' + searchVal + '"))').hide();
    }
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/p90uwdg7/

but this search is *case sensitive*, if you want to overcome this case sensitive, you need to overwrite the `contains` function

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, index, obj) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(obj[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/p90uwdg7/1/

Comment: Thank You so much I have been looking for a couple hours and finally. Thanks

Comment: @Jacecraft29 your welcome. glad that I able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Since you have all the search results in the table, you can just toogle with the entire table by using jquerys .hide() and .show() animations.

to hide the table until user searches hide the table by using .hide()

```
$("#myTable").hide();
```